# catkin_ws in raspberry pi

Tags: ros, raspberrypi, catkin-ws, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed raspbian (stretch) and ros indigo in a raspberry pi 1. I followed the document from http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi. Different from my ROS in Ubuntu, there are a lot of files and folders in ros_catkin_ws.
Now I want to create a new package in ras pi. I used the common way that I catkin_create_pkg a package in ros_catkin_ws/src. After that, however, I cannot find this package through roscd or rospack find. Also, it takes a lot of time to catkin_make the ros_catkin_ws.
I think my way of using ROS on ras pi is wrong. Could anyone tell me how to solve these problems.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277544/catkin_ws-in-raspberry-pi/) by [Hunter](https://answers.ros.org/users/32901/hunter/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2017-12-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The right way to do this is to create your own catkin package outside workspace where the whole ROS was compiled. Then you have to source your new workspace adding e.g. `source ~/my_package/devel/setup.bash` to your `.bashrc` file. If ROS still can't see your package try typing `rospack profile` command and it should find it.

---

Originally posted by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) with karma: 826 on 2017-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1